# Stretch parent div to width of table contents

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a div stretch to match the width of a child table.  At present when the browser window is narrowed the table width exceeds its parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ydu2K/

```
<div id="parentdiv" style="width: 100%; background-color: green;">
    Some text in div.
    <table style="background-color: red;">
        <tr>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>   
            <td>aaaa</td>   
            <td>aaaa</td>   
            <td>aaaa</td>   
            <td>aaaa</td>   
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible `CSS` options which you could use:

***Option 1:***

```
div {
    display: table;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/Ydu2K/3/)

---

***Option 2:***

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/Ydu2K/2/)

Comment: I'm not looking to have any of the table truncated.  Instead I would like the div to stretch to match the table width.

Answer (score 4):

```
#parentdiv {
    display: inline-block;
    /* width: 100%;  remove */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ydu2K/6/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

```
#parentdiv{
    position:relative;
}
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhFWd/1/). And by the way, remove your `width:100%; inline-style`

Comment: Yeah that did not work mate, http://jsfiddle.net/bhFWd/2/. You had some broken html which seemed to have fixed it.